# Exercise 7, Section 2.2 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification, proof-writing

> Let $W_1$ and $W_2$ be subspaces of vector space $V$ such that the set theoretic union of $W_1$ and $W_2$ is also a subspace. Prove that one of the space $W_i$ is contained in the other.

**My attempt:** Assume towards contradiction, $\exists w_1 \in W_1$ such that $w_1\notin W_2$ and $\exists w_2 \in W_2$ such that $w_2\notin W_1$. Since $w_1, w_2\in W_1\cup W_2$ and $W_1\cup W_2\leq V$, we have $w_1+w_2\in W_1 \cup W_2$. If $w_1 +w_2\in W_1$. Since $W_1\leq V$, we have $-1_F\cdot w_1=-w_1 \in W_1$. So $(w_1+w_2)-w_1=w_2\in W_1$. Thus we reach contradiction. If $w_1+w_2\in W_2$. Since $W_2\leq V$, we have $-1_F\cdot w_2=-w_2 \in W_2$. So $(w_1+w_2)-w_2=w_1\in W_2$. Thus we reach contradiction. **Is this proof correct?**

Comment: It looks correct to me.

Comment: Makes sense to me and is concise. Is the second statement of contradiction technically unnecessary, though? Once you proved a contradiction in one piece, isn't the original statement proved?

Comment: This is correct, You can also say "without loss of generality assume $w_1+w_2\in W_1$ "and skip writing out the case for the sum being in $W_2$ since the grader will be aware that the case is perfectly symmetrical.

Comment: @Moosh That is exactly I was about to write to user612713 as reply. What a coincidence! Yess… WLOG makes proof shorter.

Comment: @user612713 if we prove one piece, then original statement don’t follow, at least without any justification. One need WLOG(without loss of generality) argument to skip second statement. As you said, “technically” second statement is unnecessary.

Comment: I would argue if $w_1+w_2\in W_1\cup W_2$ then $w_1+w_2$ belongs to one of these sets. Call this set $W_1,$ changing the numbering.if necessary.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc yes that is also fine. We can also denote it by $w_1+w_2\in W_i$, for some $i\in \{1,2\}$. So $(w_1+w_2)-w_i=w_{i^c}=w_{\{1,2\}-\{i\}}\in W_i$. Which is a contradiction.